# Using flex-direction: column results in huge gap in between the two flex children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I set a breakpoint at a max-width of 800px for the footer. It is here where I want to change it from a row to a column as the screen gets smaller. When this happens however a huge gap appears between the two flex items, as if I had justify-content: space-between set on them. Any Ideas??

https://jsfiddle.net/cdky0e5m/

```js
const ham = document.querySelector('.nav-box');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuClose = document.querySelector('#menu-close');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('#left');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('#right');
const img = document.querySelector('.image-slider');
let num = 1;


ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ham.classList.add('ham-open');
    menu.style.marginLeft = '50px';
})

menuClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
    ham.classList.remove('ham-open');
    menu.style.marginLeft = '-700px';
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
    num--;
    if(num > 0) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
        console.log(num);
        console.log(img.style.backgroundImage);
    } else {
        num = 4;
        img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
    }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
    num++;
    if(num <= 4) {
        img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
        console.log(num);
        console.log(img.style.backgroundImage);
    } else {
        num = 1;
        img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
    }   
})

// window.sr = ScrollReveal();

// sr.reveal('.logo-wrap', {
//  duration: 2000
// });

// sr.reveal('.w1', {
//  duration: 2000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.w2', {
//  duration: 3000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.w3', {
//  duration: 4000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hours-line-left', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'left',
//  distance: '200px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hours-line-right', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '200px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.contact-line', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.burrito', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.taco', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.guac', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.nachos', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hot', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'left',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.back-to-top', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
// });

// sr.reveal('.btp-arrow', {
//  duration: 1500,
//  origin: 'top',
//  distance: '250px'
// });
```

Comment: Your code snippet seems completely unrelated to the issue you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.contact-line` has a height of 190px; If you set `.contact-line: {display: none;}` the gap goes away.